# Plot the Poisson CDF with the Standard Normal Distribution CDF

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, matlab, poisson-distribution

I have a question on plotting the Poisson cdf together with the standard normal distribution cdf. Below is the task description:

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X∼Poisson(λ)$ and $X^o$ be the normalized version of $X$.
The following figure shows the cdf $F_{X^o}$ of $X^o$ for some $λ∈N$ and the cdf $Φ$ of the standard normal distribution.
[image]

I have tried my best to plot as same as the given figure but still I am not able to get it looks similiar as the given figure.Below is my result:

[image]

May I know what do I miss? Below is my Matlab code:

```
pe = makedist('Normal')
x1 = -3:.1:3;
p = cdf(pe,x1);
%plot(x1,p)

x3 = -3:3;
y3 = poisscdf(x3,1);
figure
stairs(x3,y3)
hold on
plot(x1,p)
xlabel('Observation')
ylabel('Cumulative Probability')
```

Comment: The first one clearly had a much larger $\lambda$ than you do. The number of steps that you can ``see'' (before the cdf gets so close to 1 that you cannot really see the steps) is related to $\lambda$. Also, the normal approximation to a Poisson $\lambda$ is only good for $\lambda$ sufficiently large.